# ¿Como cambiar el valor de una variable con el tiempo en Python?

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente código con la intención de que el valor de la "Variable" cambie cada 10 segundos. Lo que pretendía era que al abrir un bucle en el que en un rango inferior a los primeros 10 segundos el valor de la Variable fuera 1, y después de los primeros 10 segundos el valor pasase a ser 2. Esto me sirve para otro script en el que extraigo el valor de la variable a partir de este script. Aquí pongo el código de lo que he intentado hacer:

```
import time
import threading

def timer(segundos):
    for i in range(20):

        if i < 10:
            Variable = 1
        else:
            Variable = 2
        time.sleep(segundos)

hilo = threading.Thread(target=timer, args=(10,))
hilo.start()

for i in range(60):
    time.sleep(1)
```

Aparentemente se ejecuta sin darme errores, pero el problema es que cuando intento obtener el valor de la "Variable" desde otro script no me reconoce ese valor.
¿Se os ocurre alguna sugerencia para hacer que el valor de la variable cambie cada 10 segundos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que `Variable` es una variable local de la función `timer`, y por lo tanto no puedes ser accesada desde fuera.

Solución: Declara `Variable` fuera de la función y dentro de ella definela como `global`:

```
Variable = None

def timer(segundos):
    global Variable
    for i in range(20):

        if i < 10:
            Variable = 1
        else:
            Variable = 2
        time.sleep(segundos)
```

#### Demo

Nota: cambie el límite de 10 a 3, para hacer más rápida la prueba.

```
import time
import threading

Variable = None

def timer(segundos):
    global Variable
    for i in range(20):

        if i < 3:
            Variable = 1
        else:
            Variable = 2
        print(i)
        time.sleep(segundos)

hilo = threading.Thread(target=timer, args=(10,))
hilo.start()

for i in range(60):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f"Variable {Variable}")
```

produce

```
0
Variable 1
...
Variable 1
1
Variable 1    
...
Variable 1
2
Variable 1
...
Variable 1
3
Variable 2
Variable 2
Variable 2
Variable 2
```

Comment: Igual tenías que añadir alguna advertencia sobre compartir variables globales entre hilos.

Comment: Es cierto que declarando la variable como global se ejecuta el código a la perfección mostrando el nombre del a variable que cambia cada 3 segundos. Ahora mi problema es que por ejemplo si intento obtener ese valor cambiante (por ejemplo hago un gráfico de color azul, y a los 3 segundos quiero que cambie a color rojo), pero para eso creo que debería abrir un nuevo hilo porque se sale de lo tratado en este tema. Muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta, y espero que esto sirva de ayuda para otros iniciados en programación como yo.